# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'Standard' Fluent NHibernate

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to map my database to NHibernate (coming from EF). All seems well until this code

```
 private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
 {
    return Fluently.Configure().Database(
        MySqlConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(
        c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("ConnectionString")
    )
   )
   .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MyAutofacModule>())
   .BuildSessionFactory();
  }
```

Please excuse the formatting, The purpose of this code is to demonstrate that The .Standard class is not there for some reason. I haven't found anyone else with this issue either. Any pointers or relevant information I could provide please let me know and I will gladly facilitate. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, when using Fluent NHibernate there is a difference between

```
MySqlConfiguration
```

and

```
MySQLConfiguration
```

Easy to miss, so if you're having this same issue this is what you (and I!) did wrong.